# Import Data from TXT file to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have a txt file with around 0.8 million rows in it. i want to import it into SQL. i have tried converting it into CSV as well. but excel is not allowing 0.8 million rows at a time.

Comment: Split it into two files, not sure if this is the correct platform to ask these kinds of questions.

Comment: AFAIK the maximum number of rows can be configured in excel. But for your task there are better programs than Excel. I would use awk, or even better: a php script

Comment: I had to delete my answer cause the code was looping indefinately/for longer time than max execution time.. Ill make some changes and reply back if it workes..

Comment: @Dinesh thanks a lot dinesh. waiting for your answer.  max execution time is not a problem for me. i can adjust this in my server. try with simple data (i.E. 10 lines) if it works, please post your answer below... waiting...

Answer (score 3):

Try a simple [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command. Assuming your example data is in `sample.txt` and you have the necessary permissions, it should be accomplished from the shell as:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'sample.txt' INTO TABLE sqlTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

Comment: #1045 - Access denied for user 'hgspl'@'localhost' (using password: YES) #ERROR ---- **QRERY** LOAD DATA INFILE 'public_html/big.txt' INTO TABLE sqlTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'

Comment: You need [FILE permissions](http://thinkinglemur.com/index.php/2009/06/load-data-infile-and-file-permissions-on-mysql/)... use `GRANT FILE ON *.* to youruser@"%";` Finally, note the FILE permission [must be granted globally on the server](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/40110)

Answer (score 2):

Use `mysqlimport`

Something like

```
mysqlimport --columns='co_no,pd_ch' my_db sample.txt
```

Probably have to play around with it to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL Workbench will help you a lot. If you need to modify the file first, use a scripting language such as Python. Excel is not a good option for that much data.